# Angular JS - Connect to Woocommerce OAuth v1

Tags: javascript, wordpress, angularjs, oauth

I'm trying to (unsuccesfully) authenticate myself to the rest service.

I was tryng [this library](https://github.com/ddo/oauth-1.0a) to create all the params [listed here](http://maxrice.github.io/woocommerce/rest-api/) and I'm creating the request in this way:

```
$scope.oauth = new OAuth({
    consumer: {
        public: 'ck_d34c32d9c7f6fc1ddb6e85879fc4de89',
        secret: 'cs_1867e5e54ce054dde7cf463ad78ee6f9'
    },
    signature_method: 'HMAC-SHA1'
});

var request_data = {
        url: 'http://belfiore.link-me.it/wc-api/v1/orders',
        method: 'GET',
    }
    $scope.data = $scope.oauth.authorize(request_data);

    $scope.url = rawurlencode(request_data.url) + "&" + 
                "oauth_consumer_key"+"%3D"+rawurlencode($scope.data.oauth_consumer_key)+
                "%26"+"oauth_nonce"+"%3D"+rawurlencode($scope.data.oauth_nonce)+
                "%26"+"oauth_signature_method"+"%3D"+rawurlencode($scope.data.oauth_signature_method)+
                "%26"+"oauth_timestamp"+"%3D"+rawurlencode($scope.data.oauth_timestamp)+
                "%26"+"oauth_signature"+"%3D"+rawurlencode($scope.data.oauth_signature);

    var call = $http.get($scope.url);
    call.success(function(res) {
        console.log(res);
    });
    call.error(function(res) {
        console.log(res);
    });
```

but i keep getting this answer:

`"Cannot GET /http%3A%2F%2Fbelfiore.link-me.it%2Fwc-api%2Fv1%2Forders&amp;oauth_consumer_key%3Dck_d34c32d9c7f6fc1ddb6e85879fc4de89%26oauth_nonce%3DwkeLtFTh6WAuxDQGqnpzxAWYOQiHnHSr%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D10%26oauth_signature%3DjFhPbKHnvMEvYf20w1vN3TAV5Ds%3D"`

Any help? I googled out to find some tutorial or angular ready library fot OAuth1 but I found nothing...

thanks in advance

Comment: You shouldn't try to manually encode your url. Then, for a better start, you should have a look to http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http - Note that you can pass your URL parameters as a map. Good luck!

Comment: are you got solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of the [oauth-1.0a](https://github.com/ddo/oauth-1.0a) lib

I did not try angularjs yet but just a quick glance, please follow the below code:

```
$http({
    url: request_data.url,
    method: request_data.method,
    params: $scope.oauth.authorize(request_data)
});
```

Comment: It's there any library for ng? Can you help me with authentication with woocommerce? I can't get it work.

Answer (score 0):

`rawurlencode` is a php function, however,you should use  javascript function `encodeURIComponent` to replace it.